# Using POST and GET to Exchange Data Through Endpoints

Tags: javascript, json, post, get, spotify

I'm attempting to build a web app using [Spotify's web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/) however, I find their tutorial lacking. The way it works is data is requested using POST and GET functionality and sent back using JSON. Seems easy enough, want to get information about an artist? Just call GET `https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0OdUWJ0sBjDrqHygGUXeCF` and you get a nice JSON document with information about the requested artist.

The problem is I don't know how to make that GET call. jQuery has get and post methods both with "data" parameters but I'm not sure on the syntax necessary, especially when it comes to exchanging an authorization code for an access token. If you visit [Spotify's authorization guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) and scroll to step 4 of the Authorization Code Flow you can see I need to make a POST call to `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token`. The call must have 3 request body parameters and 1 header parameter and upon succession a JSON file with the appropriate data is in the response body.

My question is how do I make POST and GET calls that have body parameters and header parameters and how do I extract the JSON data from the response body after a successful call?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from their [code examples & libraries](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/) and this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMPerez/62wafrm7/), their getUserData request is nothing but a simple ajax call, which contains their url and a headers object (which contains a prefix string concatenated with the accessToken) as parameters:

```
    function getUserData(accessToken) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
            headers: {
               'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            }
        });
    }
```

Generally, when you need to pass parameters in an `$.ajax` call, just do as shown above, or construct an object first and include it like this:

```
YourObj = {
   url: "your url here",
   param2: "param val 2",
   param3: "param val 3",
   ...
}

$.ajax(YourObj).done(function(data){
   //do something with the returned data here, e.g.
   console.log("data: ", data);
});
```

This approach can be useful if your parameters are dependent on other values which are not so readily avalable.